# Liquibase refactor or undo changeset in multiple regions

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, undo, changeset

I am new to liquibase and have created a sample table utilizing a spring boot + liquibase project. My initial changelog to create the table in file 'createSampleTable.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.7"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.7
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.7.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="Russ">
        <comment>A sample table to see if liquibase works</comment>

        <createTable tableName="testy">
                <column name="VALUE" type="varchar(32)"/>
        </createTable>

        <insert tableName="testy">
            <column name="value" value="Hello, world!"/>
        </insert>

        <insert tableName="testy">
            <column name="value" value="Riddikulus!"/>
        </insert>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Now that I've verified my liquibase configuration, this same deployment has run in our 2 lower regions (dev and test) but we have not yet stood up stage or prod. I would like to "undo" the sample table and start creating my real database structure.

My understanding is I have two options: conditional drop table, rollback

I am currently trying to implement the conditional drop table [as the documentation states](http://www.liquibase.org/2008/10/dealing-with-changing-changesets.html) but the proposed attributes are not recognized even though the [preconditions documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) clearly states the `onFail` annotation should be recognized. Here is my implementation of the proposed solution (this is the current contents of the 'createSampleTable.xml' file:

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.7"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.7
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.7.xsd">

    <!-- The documentation for liquibase says if you ever create a changeset
        in error that you never really wanted to follow this approach.
        The general idea is to delete the original changeset and then
        provide a new changeset that should only run if the original changset
        has run as well. In essence this allows us to remove a naughty change
        entirely from the code and prevent it from being run in new
        environments while providing an "undo" changeset to be ran in
        environments where this changeset has unfortunately already ran.

        Documentation referenced and approach taken:
        http://www.liquibase.org/2008/10/dealing-with-changing-changesets.html

        To satisfy developer's curiosity and prevent them from having to
        look up the history in the repository the original changeset of id=1
        was simply to create a sample table to make sure the initial liquibase
        config was working.
    -->

    <changeSet id="1-undo" author="Russ">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <changeSetExecuted id="1" author="Russ" changeLogFile="liquibase/createSampleTable.xml" />
        </preConditions>

        <dropTable tableName="testy"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

However, when running this both the `onFail` attribute and the 
`<changeSetExecuted>` tag are unrecognized by the schema. After this I tried to implement the maven plugin to rollback, but this executes on the build, so this target will only ever resolve one region.

What is the generally accepted approach for undoing changes? Does the approach differ if you're implementing a spring boot liquibase project?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your applied schema is quite old (1.7).

Check your included version (if Maven, check your pom).

You should be able to use the required tags if you use the 3.1 version xml schema:

```
<databaseChangeLog                                                                                                                     
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                                                                            
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                                          
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"                                                                    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

...

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Note the schema `dbchangelog-3.1.xsd`

If using Maven, the above schema works with the following plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```